# Changing every line of a text file in python

Tags: python, file, append

I have a file with 50,000 lines. All of the lines are of the form of:

A,B

A,B

A,B

and so on...
I would like to edit the file (or even better, create a new one) such that at the end my text file will look like so:

A

A

A

...

Basically erasing the , and B.
How can I do it in the most efficient way?

```
   # Create a new file for the new lines to be appended to

   f = open("file.txt", "r")
      for line in f:
          # Take the A,B form and send only the A to a new file
```

Thanks

Comment: well, for starters, you won't be able to iterate over `f` if you open in in `'w'` mode... and furthermore, it will truncate your file, so you will lose your data... so don't do that...

Comment: I don't mind losing my data as I have a copy, I might as well create a new file, doesn't matter to me.

Comment: right, but the point is *you won't be able to read your data this way*. Usually, you simply open two files, the file you are reading (opened in 'r' mode), and write to a new file (opened seperately in 'w' mode)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available to introduce you to file processing.  If you work through a couple of those, you should be able to answer this question and several more that follow.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thanks, make perfect sense, will do that like that, editing now

Comment: In particular, this problem is likely better handled by a system utility, such as `awk` or `sed` on UNIX (Linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty python script, but...

```
# Open the file as read
f = open("text.txt", "r+")
# Create an array to hold write data
new_file = []
# Loop the file line by line
for line in f:
  # Split A,B on , and use first position [0], aka A, then add to the new array
  only_a = line.split(",")
  # Add
  new_file.append(only_a[0])
# Open the file as Write, loop the new array and write with a newline
with open("text.txt", "w+") as f:
  for i in new_file:
    f.write(i+"\n")
```